# Avspeechsynthesizer Utterance Audio File, UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, swift, audio, uilocalnotification, avspeechsynthesizer

I am looking for a way to save an AVSpeechSynthesizer utterance instance as an audio file.  There are a few similar questions on stackoverflow regarding this, but they all seem to be from ios 6-7.

Is there any way in swift to create a text to speech audio file?

If so, can I use this audio file as a UILocalNotification sound? Which audio file format is necessary to do so?

Thank you

Comment: Did you find a way to achieve that? :)

Comment: @Alex im sorry, i did not. if you figure it out please drop a link here

Answer (score 0):

AVSpeechSynthesizer does not have the same feature list as NSSpeechSynthesizer. Try the following:

```
let speech = NSSpeechSynthesizer()

let url = NSURL(----your path----)
speech.startSpeakingString("whatever", toURL: url)
```

You won't hear anything but your file will be saved

Comment: speech.startSpeakingString with URL is not available for ios. its only of macOS.